# Error when running Spark on a google cloud instance

Tags: out-of-memory, apache-spark, rdd, google-hadoop

I'm running a standalone application using Apache Spark and when I load all my data to a RDD as a textfile I got the following error:

```
15/02/27 20:34:40 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread stdout writer for python
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFSInputStream.<init>(GoogleHadoopFSInputStream.java:81)
   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.open(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:764)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:427)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:78)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:51)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:233)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:210)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:99)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:242)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1460)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:203)
Exception in thread "stdout writer for python" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
   at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFSInputStream.<init>(GoogleHadoopFSInputStream.java:81)
   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.open(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:764)
   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:427)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.<init>(LineRecordReader.java:78)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:51)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:233)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:210)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:99)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:263)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:230)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(PythonRDD.scala:242)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:204)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1460)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:203)
```

I thought that was related with the fact I'm caching the whole RDD to memory with the `cache` function. I haven't noticed any change when I rid off this function from my code. SO I keep getting this error.

My RDD is derived from several text files inside a directory that is located in a google cloud bucket.

Could you help me to solve this error?

Comment: Did you manually create the cluster, or did you use something like [bdutil](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bdutil)? What version of Spark are you using?

Comment: @DennisHuo I used bdutil to create the cluster. I'm using spark 1.2.0

Comment: What machine-type are you using? It would also help to peek at the contents of your `/home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-env.sh` and `/home/hadoop/spark-install/conf/spark-defaults.conf` files.

Comment: @DennisHuo in my case I have just the `/home/hadoop/hadoop-install` in my machine, I mean my master node. I checked and I don't have `/home/hadoop/spark-instal`l subdir. I have so the file `/home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf/hadoop-env.sh` anyway. Does that one work out for you?

Comment: @DennisHuo my master machine and my worker machines are the following type: n1-standard-4 (4 vCPU, 15 GB memory)

Comment: Ah, how did you install Spark then? Did you just download it yourself?

Comment: Yep, basically I just deployed the instances through `bdutil deploy` and I did the following commands in my master instance after downloaded the spark to my home dir: 
`export SPARK_HOME=~/spark-1.2.0/` `cp /home/hadoop/hadoop-install/conf/core-site.xml $SPARK_HOME/conf/` `cd $SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars` `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/hadoop-lib/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar` `export SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_HOME/lib_managed/jars/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar`

Comment: @DennisHuo I just added my answer to your last suggestion and scenario. Would you mind take a look? And thank you very much for your interest and availability to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Spark requires a fair bit of configuration tuning depending on cluster size, shape, and workload, and out-of-the-box, probably won't work for realistically-sized workloads.

When using `bdutil` to deploy, the best way to get Spark is actually to use the officially-supported bdutil plugin, simply with:

```
./bdutil -e extensions/spark/spark_env.sh deploy
```

Or equivalently as shorthand:

```
./bdutil -e spark deploy
```

This will make sure the gcs-connector and memory settings, etc., are all properly configured in Spark.

You can also theoretically use bdutil to install Spark directly on your existing cluster, though this is less thoroughly-tested:

```
# After you've already deployed the cluster with ./bdutil deploy:
./bdutil -e spark run_command_group install_spark -t all
./bdutil -e spark run_command_group spark_configure_startup -t all
./bdutil -e spark run_command_group start_spark -t master
```

This should be the same as if you had just run `./bdutil -e spark deploy` originally. If you had deployed with `./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh deploy` then all the above commands need to actually start with `./bdutil -e my_custom_env.sh -e spark run_command_group`.

In your case, the relevant Spark memory settings were probably related to `spark.executor.memory` and/or `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` and/or `SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY`

EDIT: On a related note, we [just released bdutil-1.2.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gcp-hadoop-announce/uVJ_6y9cGKM) which defaults to Spark 1.2.1, and also adds improved Spark driver memory settings and YARN support.